# Nodejs and raw-socket package

Tags: node.js, raw-sockets

I have a nodejs application that should start when I turn on the machine (I'm using Linux Ubuntu 16.04 so I put it in  the rc.local). my application uses the raw-socket package.

Since my application cannot run as root, in the rc.local, I set:

```
sudo -u myuser node myapp.js &
```

when my application calls "new raw-socket", I got an error:

```
Operation not permitted.
```

I tried different methods such as "setcap" but they don't work for me.

Furthermore, if i try to run my app after the operating system is loaded, the app works perfectly without any problem....

should I have to add something in the rc.local....did I miss something?

Comment: Maybe the Node.js runtime is assuming that some core processes are running when they haven't initialized at startup yet?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: It's just a guess. It's hard to say what's going on until you [edit] your question to include the actual stack trace for the error log, and relevant parts of your `myapp.js` file.

Comment: unfortunately myapp is quite huge and complex...I don't understand why when the system is started it works perfectly...I also tried to put myuser as root (with visudo) but it always crashes

Comment: When the system has already started, do you have to run as root then in order for it to work?

Comment: no...just writing node myapp.js (as myuser)

Comment: Then you shouldn't need root at startup either. As my initial guess indicates, your program probably relies on some core services that aren't fully initialized at startup which are necessary for the program to have access to raw sockets. I recommend either adding a stage in your program that polls maybe once a second until `Operation not permitted` no longer occurs at startup. Also stop providing root permissions, as that's a security issue especially if network communication is involved.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your time....Since the rc.local should be the last script called at the startup (right??), I tried to put a sleep of 1 minute in the rc.local. Unfortunately, it does not work again.. :(

Comment: Upgrade...I noticed that if I run the rc.local after the machine is completely loaded, I obtain the same result (it does not work). for this reason, I think the problem is related to the execution usign `sudo -u` .

Comment: I said not to run as root

Comment: I'm not running it as root....in fact in the rc.local I wrote `sudo -u myuser node myapp`. In this way, myapp run as myuser, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

`node-raw-socket` needs root access to create its raw sockets.

You will have to run

```
sudo node myapp.js
```